# Permutation seating arragement where no 2 person with same sex sit together

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> In a group of $5$ persons, there are atleast $2$ men and $2$ women. in how many diff. ways can they be seated on same side of a straight table so that no two person of same sex sit side by side? how many ways are there of such a seating if table is circular?

My solution:

$$
M= 3,\text{ }W=2,\text{ straight table}: 3!2! 
$$

```
 {Circular table}: w=3, m=2:   (3-1)! (2!)
```

Is my solution correct?

Comment: For the straight table, the arrangement must be MWMWM. There are $3!$ ways to seat the men and $2!$ ways to seat the women. For the circular table, it is impossible to avoid having at least one pair of the same gender sitting next to each other.

Comment: Does it mean at least two men and at least two women, or at least two men and (exactly) two women ? I rather think it is the former, as otherwise it could simply have been written as three men and two women...

Comment: yes, it means atleast 2 men and atleast 2 women, total members should be 5.

Comment: Sudhakshi, you need to tag the person e.g. @true blue anil for the person to get the message. Only the questioner's name needn't be tagged.

Answer (score 1):

With your clarification, it should be obvious that for the first part of the question, there are two possible configurations, viz. $MWMWM \;or\;WMWMW\;$so the ans will be $2\times 3!2!$

For the circular table illustrated for $w=3,m=2$

the women can be placed in $(3-1)!$ ways, as you have written,
but only two of the $3$ gaps can be filled by men,
which makes it impossible to fulfill the gender separation criterion.